# Visualforce Redirect for single Opportunity Record Type only

Tags: apex, visualforce, record-type, redirect

On my Opportunity object, I have one Record Type that I am looking to redirect to a custom Visualforce Page & Controller.  The other Opportunity Record Types can stay defaulted to the standard page layouts.

I have overriden the Opportunity New Button with the Visualforce below which calls my custom controller.

I receive "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" error when testing.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
public class SSPNewOpptyRedirect {

    Opportunity oppty {get; set;}
    Id recordTypeA;

    public SSPNewOpptyRedirect(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        oppty = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();

        recordTypeA = [SELECT Id
                       FROM RecordType
                       WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'New_Supply_Side_Platform' LIMIT 1].Id;                              

    }   

    public PageReference continueNextPage() {
        PageReference newPage;

        newPage = Page.SSPOpportunityEdit;

        if (Oppty.RecordTypeId != recordTypeA)
        {
            String retUrl = '006/e';
            newPage = new PageReference('/' + retUrl);
        }

        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') != null) {
            newPage.getParameters().put('RecordType', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType'));
        }

        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL') != null) {
            newPage.getParameters().put('retURL', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
        }

        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ent') != null) {
            newPage.getParameters().put('ent', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ent'));
        }

        newPage.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');

        return newPage;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="SSPNewOpptyRedirect" 
action="{!continueNextPage}"> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It helps if you include the entirety of the error message, verbatim. Knowing which line is throwing the error (and in which class) is important for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The only query that's casting to a single SObject is the one for Record Type, so that's almost certainly where the error is. Unless you are putting underscores in your Record Type names, you want `DeveloperName` instead of `Name`.

```
recordTypeA = [SELECT Id
                   FROM RecordType
                   WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND DeveloperName = 'New_Supply_Side_Platform' LIMIT 1].Id;
```

It's always a good idea to test your queries in DevConsole, Workbench or your IDE to make sure you're getting the results you want.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I'm now receiving the following error after making that change.  Any ideas?                                                                                                         
**Cyclical server-side forwards detected: /apex/sspopportunityedit?ent=Opportunity&nooverride=1&RecordType=012f2000000DyOh&retURL=%2F006%2Fo**

Comment: I don't think you wan't `nooverride=1` when redirecting to the VF page for the one record type.

Comment: Do you propose this condition should be removed entirely, Thomas?  I'm not sure what's wrong with the code.